# how to evaluate variable in xpath using How.find?

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using the below syntax to evaluate the Xpath in run time

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@id='icombobox_Text_cboRefPriority']")]
public IWebElement txt_RefPriority { get; set; }
```

the above works perfectly , however in case when i need to select a xpath using the variable it does not work.

e.g :

```
Context.LoginName => will read a value from a XL/XML which can change dnamically

[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@id='"+Context.LoginName+"']")]
public IWebElement txt_RefPriority { get; set; }
```

How to resolve the problem ?

Comment: Try printing the string after generating the XPath. Most probably the value the variable is holding is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The string of `Using` is evaluated in *compile* time, so it must be constant. For that reason it isn't possible to use variables in `FindsBy`. You will get the error

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

If you want to locate the element using variable you need to locate the element when you want to use it using `FindElement`

```
IWebElement txt_RefPriority = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='"+Context.LoginName+"']"));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am also using the same way like Driver.FindElementBy ....

Thought if there could be a solution in FindsBy , so posted the query